# handling lookup tables with deleted records and databound controls

Tags: c#, database

I have a table *Resource* with a field *Type*. *Type* is a lookup into the table *ResourceType*.

So for instance ResourceType might have:
1: Books
2: Candy
3: Both

And Resource might have
1: Tom's Grocery, 2
2: Freds News, 3

It would display as: Tom's Grocery    Candy

Now lets say I am using a databound combobox for the resource type and the third record is deleted from ResourceType, we of course get an error when *Fred's News* is displayed.  I could simply put a marker in (perhaps an asterisk), indicating that it has been deleted, rather than actually delete it.  It shows up as **Both* in the textbox portion of the combo and I am content.

However, I would not want it to show up as an *option* in the dropdown.  Is this too much to ask from databound fields?  Must I write my own code to load the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding a deleted column was not enough - there had to be a way to see a deleted record in the text portion of a combo box while at the same time filtering out deleted records in the drop down.

In the end, I wrote a custom user control to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a bit Deleted column to the lookup table.  When you delete a type, set Deleted = 1.  When you pull back ResourceTypes, only pull out ResourceTypes where Deleted = 0 and then bind to the dropdown.

**Edit:** 
How are you getting the dataset that you're binding to the dropdownlist?  Are you using drag and drop datasets?  I really haven't worked with datasets like that in years, but I'm pretty sure you can change the Get sql to what you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I already have most of that built into the solution - but I must be binding wrong.  If I only pull back records where deleted = 0, I get exceptions - I'm guessing because the textbox can't be filled from the record set.

I guess I'm not sure how to bind the textbox display to one dataset - the one with all the records - and the dropdown to a filtered dataset.